# Objective-C mangled names (_OBJC_CLASS_ vs .objc_class_name_)

Tags: objective-c, static-linking, name-mangling, nm

I was trying to fix some unresolved references while linking libraries and noticed that the missing class is defined as

```
 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_CocoaRenderView
```

by `nm`.
However, if I check the library where this class is defined, I found this:

```
00000000 t -[CocoaRenderView initCocoaRenderView:]
000000f0 t -[CocoaRenderView initCocoaRenderViewFullScreen:]
000000e0 t -[CocoaRenderView nsOpenGLContext]
00000000 A .objc_class_name_CocoaRenderView
```

So here is the question - what is the difference b/w prefixes `_OBJC_CLASS_` and `.objc_class_name_`? It doesn't seem helping linker to resolve symbols properly.

Any links would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the symbols prefixed with `.objc_class_name_` are the class names (strings) and are of type "Absolute Global Symbol" (`A`) where as the `_OBJC_CLASS_` symbols are of type "Text Section Symbol" (`t`).

I have not studied the implementation but they are clearly different things and I am not sure this will really help you very much so hopefully someone who works closer to the metal will be able to help you further.

At the end of the day, however, you seem capable enough to verify that the class is not defined in the object file and understand what the linker is complaining about, which is as about as far as I take such investigations.

Comment: thanks! this makes sense. i'm also curious why symbols like `00000000 t -[CocoaRenderView initCocoaRenderView:]` were not mangled at all?

Comment: however, does this imply that the class was not defined where it should be defined (the file which has `00000000 A .objc_class_name_CocoaRenderView` in nm output)?

Comment: Yeah what doesn't make sense to me is that those methods are defined but the linker is still complaining. What is the file you ran `nm` on and is it being linked in?

Comment: Turned out to be a silly case - linker didn't link these files as they were compiled to the wrong architecture (i386 instead of x86_64). Thank you anyways!